# django channels vs daphene

Tags: django, django-channels, daphne, asgi, uvicorn

I am little bit confused about the main roles of django-channels and uvicorn server. I have read a lot of blogs but did not get much clarification.

If we can implement an ASGI server for websockets using channels, then why do we need asgi server seperately like daphene or uvicorn?

Comment: Daphne/Uvicorn are to Django Channels(and other ASGI frameworks) what Gunicorn/uWSGI are to Django(and other WSGI frameworks like Flask). I hope this helps

Comment: pip install -U channels , by installing channels we ca implement asgi server then why we need daphne

Comment: It seems you didn't understand my comparison above. Daphne is an application server while Django channels is a framework (well, hooked to Django). You use the framework to develop the logic, while the application server runs the code. Please read about gunicorn and uWSGI. It will help you understand more of what Daphne and Uvicorn are

Answer (score 2):

Daphne is a [ASGI server](https://www.uvicorn.org/#alternative-asgi-servers) while Django Channels is an [ASGI Framework](https://www.uvicorn.org/#asgi-frameworks) for Django.
Links have been taken from [www.uvicorn.org](http://www.uvicorn.org).

Also reference from another [blog](https://arunrocks.com/a-guide-to-asgi-in-django-30-and-its-performance/) is mentioned below:

> Channels was created to support asynchronous protocols like Websockets and long polling HTTP. Django applications still run synchronously. Channels is an official Django project but not part of core Django.
>
> Django Async project will support writing Django applications with asynchronous code in addition to synchronous code. Async is a part of Django core.
>
> Both were led by Andrew Goodwin.
>
> These are independent projects in most cases. You can have a project that uses either or both. For example if you need to support a chat application over web sockets, then you can use Channels without using Django’s ASGI interface. On the other hand if you want to make an async function in a Django view, then you will have to wait for Django’s Async support for views.